# Absolute value laws - $|a \cdot b| = |a| \cdot |b|$ - Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have the expression \begin{vmatrix}{ \dfrac{ (-1)\sqrt{n}(x+3) }{ \sqrt{n+1} } }\end{vmatrix}

We know that the absolute value laws state that $|a \cdot b| = |a| \cdot |b|$.

Therefore, would I be correct in saying that $ \begin{vmatrix}{ \dfrac{ (-1)\sqrt{n}(x+3) }{ \sqrt{n+1} } }\end{vmatrix} = \dfrac{ |x+3||-1|\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} }$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You could simplify $|-1|$ a little...

Comment: Yes, but get rid of that |-1|, of course.

Comment: @dxiv I changed it to absolute value laws. Hopefully that is correct.

Comment: I will get rid of the $-1$. This was just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score -1):

No. We have

$\begin{vmatrix}{ \dfrac{ (-1)\sqrt{n}(x+3) }{ \sqrt{n+1} } }\end{vmatrix}= \dfrac{ \sqrt{n}|(x+3)| }{ \sqrt{n+1} } $

Edit: You are right. My mistake, I have read $ \dfrac{ |x+3|-1\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} }$

Comment: That's not "no". That's "yes but you didn't go far enough".

Comment: @Fred I think you don't answer the question.